# How can i get real-time tracking results?

Tags: google-maps, gps, kml, google-earth, driving-directions

We are trying to achieve is to collect **fake gps tracks** on some route without going in real time.

We first realized by using maps.google.com we can download **kml** file from any direction between designated points.But these points **depend on shape of the road** where if we go through a bridge,kml file comes within only begin and end points of it.(that's Directions Service)

I know this task sounds some lazy,but if there is a way to do this with Google or another service or by implementing some code on given route,we have to try it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by using GIS desktop tool where points can be added manually.
By saving table as .kml,I achieved to collect gps route.It may not look GPS track alike,but it was to easy to handle the situation.